# cvSobel with 16 bit grayscale images

Tags: c, opencv

I have a 10 bit grayscale image that I like to use the cvSobel function. The documentation is not clear if it can accept 16 bit grayscale images. When I try to make this work, I get an exception from OpenCV.

In my VC++ when I look at the function, this is what I am seeing.

```
 CVAPI(void) cvSobel( const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst,
            int xorder, int yorder,
            int aperture_size CV_DEFAULT(3));
```

I tried to make destination 32F but still crash.

Answer (score 2):

It says [here](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm#decl_cvSobel):

> To avoid overflow, the function requires 16-bit destination image if
>   the source image is 8-bit. The result can be converted back to 8-bit
>   using cvConvertScale or cvConvertScaleAbs functions. Besides 8-bit
>   images the function can process 32-bit floating-point images. Both
>   source and destination must be single-channel images of equal size or
>   ROI size.

So, you could probably convert your source to 8bit and then declare the destination as 16bit.

It would also help if you could post the specific part of the code if this doesn't work.

Comment: This is clear. However converting image to 8 bit would result in loss which I like to avoid, hence the question.

Comment: What happens if you convert source to CV_32F and destination to CV_64F?  You will not lose info this way. Can you provide a minimal example with your image initialization?

Comment: I am able to get it working. I was passing raw image data, it turns out, I must have passed the image with headers. Simple mistake, only understood once I get the openCV to build with PDB files so that I can debug.